# Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

When data is posting using webapi than I am facing this error:

I donthave primary key in my table how to add entity key

> {"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(SELECT\n      `collection`.`CustomerID`, \n
>   `collection`.`AmountRecevied`, \n' at line 1"}

```
   public postUser(collection collection)
    {
        try
        {

            cs.collections.Add(collection);
            cs.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage PostUser(collection Collection)
    {
        if (Collection == null)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "not created");

        if (obj.PostUser(Collection))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, TheModelFactory.create(Collection));
        }
        else
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not save to the database");
    }
```

Comment: when I amchecking query runnging in database without error

Comment: what data you send to the server and what link?

Comment: {"CustomerID":"12122","AmountRecevied":"2000","Date_Time":"","longitude":"17.3660° N","AgentID":"15","Money_Receipt_No":"56654","Payment_Mode":"cash","Money_Receipt_Photo":"","latitude":"78.4760° E"}  through fiddler   http://localhost:12426/api/Insert/PostUser

Comment: your problem can bee the "°" character from latitude and longitude

Comment: I put varchar(45) in db

Comment: as you said I put null for long and lati but still error coming

Comment: no one have about my problem?

Comment: I don't have primary key in  my table  may be that reason error is occurred so how to add entity key?

Comment: try to rename this column Date_Time

Comment: no TotPeRo  I don't have primary key in my table I think that's the problem is that right